# Strange bug when appending output to file

Tags: linux, bash, append

I have a strange bug when appending to file in bash where text gets deleted even though I’m telling it to append.

I have a bash-script where I do the following

```
echo "Run program" > foo.txt
./fortran_program >> foo.txt
```

The program fortran_program (a stripped down version of it that gives the same result) is:

```
program main 
write(*,*) 'A'
write(*,*) 'B'
end program
```

This should give me `Run program AB` in foo.txt after the execution. However I find `Run B` instead so the original text has been overwritten and `A` is not included.

I did `strace -f ./script` and found the following output that looks relevant:

```
...
[pid 36681] open("foo.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
[pid 36681] dup2(3, 1)                  = 1
[pid 36681] close(3)                    = 0
...
[pid 34260] write(1, " A\n", 3)         = 3
[pid 34260] lseek(1, 0, SEEK_CUR)       = 3
[pid 34260] ftruncate(1, 3)             = 0
[pid 34260] write(1, " B\n", 3)         = 3
...
```

From my very limited understanding of this it seems that `A` is written to the file, then `lseek` is called which gives that the file is only 3 characters long (same length as the first string I try to write) and then `ftruncate` truncates it at 3 characters (i.e. `Run`) and then writes `B` to the file.

The following program in c (`echo "Run program" > foo.txt; ./c_program`) reproduces the behaviour so it seems it is not just fortran related (though only ifort compiled code gives the error above)

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(){
  int n, f;
  f = open("foo.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0666);
  write(f," A\n",3);
  n = lseek(f,0,SEEK_CUR);
  ftruncate(f,n);
  write(f," B\n",3);
}
```

The strange thing is that when I run the code above on my laptop it does the expected thing and gives me `Run Program AB` so it seems logical that `lseek` causes the problem on the cluster I use, but I know to little of it (and I have no idea how to fix it) so I'm asking it here.

> Why does this happen and most importantly: is there a way to fix this?

This is quite annoying since to avoid it I need to make a temp file and pipe the output from the run into this and then condencate the original file with the temp-file afterwards to get the desired output to `foo.txt`.

System specifications where I have the problem:

```
ifort 14.0.2 20140120
gcc 4.4.7 20120313
Linux cluster 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 27 15:55:46 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and where it's working

```
gcc 4.8.5
Darwin laptop 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: I added some more output from the strace if it's relevant. I don't know what to look for though (apart from the obvious) so please let me know if I should just include all of it.

Comment: Is the LD_PRELOAD environment variable set to something on the cluster? It could be that you use a redefined lseek function.

Comment: This could be a latency-related issue. What if you put a sleep (10 seconds or something stupidly large) between the echo and the run in the bash script?

Comment: @AnthonyScemama No it's empty. And I do not preload any libraries in my bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

My Fortran is very rusty, but I think that by default Fortran treats each `write` as a separate record, which is resulting in the new lines (and the seeks? - which seems a buggy to me, too).

If you want to suppress that behavior, this might be a little closer to what you're looking for:

```
program main 
write(*,100, advance='no') 'A'
write(*,100, advance='no') 'B'
100 format (A)
end program
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code I added was just an example to reproduce the bug. I have hundreds of writes in the acctual code(s) I'm running and want to store as logfiles so it's not a good option for me to change all the code. Anyway I tried your fix and `Run program` after appending now becomes `Ru `. strace shows that it does combind to `AB` (`write(1, "AB", 2)`) but after it still calls `lseek(1, 0, SEEK_CUR)` and `ftruncate`.