# (java-/coffee-)script test file wrote output to itself... strange thing

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I was trying see if a script would work. (I'm very new to coffee-script).
I tried opening this (coffeeTest.js) file in the browser:

```js
require 'coffee-script';

(function (){
        console.log("this is from coffeeTest");
        alert"hi from coffee";
        }
)
```

Immediately before this, I had set exported the PATH of mongoDB in the .bash_profile, created a replica set, checked the version of python, and with 'modules' saw all the modules of python. Exited python. Did *npm install* of coffee-script from the directory of the script, and did *node coffeeTest.js*. Then I opened coffeeTest.js in the browser.
the result (after a second or so) was output in the browser that seems to be all the output to the StdOutput (of this terminal) for about the past 10 days maybe. 
and the contents of the coffeeTest.js had this output also ... about 0,5MB and this was written to the file.

Could someone please say what happened? ...

I tried a few times to rerun the same filename in the browser (reload, or back button also I think) and the same thing happened... 
but after renaming the file I can't seem to reproduce the result.

(It's possible that the script maybe not precisely the original, since I tried changing the require stmt and comment out the Console.log to see it I could get the Alert...)

Very new to this, please excuse if not exactly the right place, or not asked well enough... But it's strange...

Thanks in advance... v

The closest I found of something similar (like re-writing contents) is:
[Strange bug when appending output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356665/strange-bug-when-appending-output-to-file)

Comment: It shouldn't do *anything* since your file doesn't do anything except declare a function.

Comment: so it shouldn't, right. but there's output in the browser... and the re-written contents of the script file...

Comment: Sorry in advance if my assumption is faulty, but why would you open a file written for nodejs with a browser ?

Comment: Sorry for the second comment, I forgot to include this:
To get a file written in coffeescript to be usable in your browser, the best, (at least the most recommended way) is to compile them first.

By the way that's how we write a function in coffeescript:

`test = () ->
  console.log 'this is from coffeeTest'
  alert 'hi from coffee'
test()`

Comment: hi tagkiller, thanks for the response, assumption 1 is not faulty, I didn't know any better... so the question still stands.  anyway, are you saying that the text string I used is the same as the one you/coffeescript uses in a test?? ... could it be that because of the way 'we write a function in coffeescript', that the browser 'recognised that' and so did what it did... log everything to the output and a file on disk? thanks in advance for your response, v :)